# Divide a 2D list into 4 parts and then transpose it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that can transpose a list, but I don't know how to separate that list into 4 equal chunks and then transpose each one individually using that function.  Here's how I'm transposing these lists:

```
def rotation(list,m) :
    newlist= [[0] * m for _ in range(m)]
    for i in range(m) :
        for j in range(m):
            newlist[j][m-1-i] = list[i][j]
    for i in range(m) :
        for j in range(m):
            list[i][j] = newlist[i][j]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use Numpy for for matrix operations

```
import numpy as np
npmatrix = np.array(mymatrix) # mymatrix is your 2D basic list
mymatrix_transpose = npmatrix.T
print npmatrix.shape #dimenssion of the matrix
npmatrix1 = npmatrix[0:npmatrix.shape[0]/2,0:npmatrix.shape[1]/2]# the upper right chunk
npmatrix1_transpos = npmatrix1.T
# you can get the other 3 parts in the same way
```